# Rails 3 ancestry model belongs_to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, data-mapping, ancestry

I'm trying to implement a nested set that belongs to another model using the Ancestry gem.

Using the old Posts/Comments example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Post
has_many comments

Comment
belongs_to post
has_ancestry
```

So if I have a Comment which belongs to a Post with ID of 1, I want any children of that Comment to inherit the Post ID.

Is there a nice Rails-Way to do this?